# Bootstrap: Form text areas "splitting" on mobile

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am in the process of converting our site to be responsive using Bootstrap. Nearing the end, I've come across an issue that's happening only on mobile, where the text areas within a form seem to "split" into two on the screen (screenshot below). No other elements are having any sort of issues and are sizing as expected. I have not set any "sizing" CSS properties. Any ideas?

[Text Areas splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiFBk.png)

HTML: (attaching just a small snippet as this page is very long, the "childhistory" div is a child only to the "container" and "col" divs):

```
<div id="childhistory">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <p><label><strong>Has the child ever been hospitalized for mental health issue?</strong> (Include location, dates, length, and reason)</label></p>
                                            <textarea id="mentalhealth_hospitilization" name="mentalhealth_hospitilization" cols="50" rows="2" tabindex="142"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <p><label><strong>Has the child had previous mental health services?</strong> (If so, list agency, clinician, and periods of services)</label></p>
                                    <textarea id="mentalhealth_services" name="mentalhealth_services" cols="50" rows="2" tabindex="143"></textarea>
                                    <p><label><strong>Has the child seen a psychiatrist before?</strong> (If so, include location, clinician, diagnosis, and reason)</label></p>
                                    <textarea id="seenpsychiatrist" name="seenpsychiatrist" cols="50" rows="2" tabindex="144"></textarea>
                                    <p><label><strong>Has the child ever hurt themselves or attempted suicide?</strong> (Include details)</label></p>
                                    <textarea id="selfharm_history" name="selfharm_history" cols="50" rows="2" tabindex="145"></textarea>
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing the cols="50" to a lower number that would fit within the mobile screen?

Comment: @NathanBayne I have not due to the fact that this would then make the text areas appear very small on other screen sizes.

Comment: if you try using a media query for each view such as Desktop, Tablet and mobile. for the likes of the mobile view, I would go for the following:

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```css
  #childhistory textarea {
    width: 45%;
  }


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #childhistory textarea {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
  }
  }
```

```html
<div id="childhistory">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
        <p><label><strong>Has the child ever been hospitalized for mental health issue?</strong> (Include location, dates, length, and reason)</label></p>
         <textarea id="mentalhealth_hospitilization" name="mentalhealth_hospitilization" rows="2" tabindex="142"></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
                                    
   <p><label><strong>Has the child had previous mental health services?</strong> (If so, list agency, clinician, and periods of services)</label></p>
   
   <textarea id="mentalhealth_services" name="mentalhealth_services" rows="2" tabindex="143"></textarea>
   <p><label><strong>Has the child seen a psychiatrist before?</strong> (If so, include location, clinician, diagnosis, and reason)</label></p>
   
   <textarea id="seenpsychiatrist" name="seenpsychiatrist" rows="2" tabindex="144"></textarea>
   <p><label><strong>Has the child ever hurt themselves or attempted suicide?</strong> (Include details)</label></p>
```